# How do I make my weapon toggle script scroll up and down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So What you do is attach the script to the parent object and when you scroll it will scroll through the weapons. The problem is I can scroll down but when i try to scroll up it just takes me back to the top weapon.

Here is my code:

```
public class toggleweapon : MonoBehaviour
{
public int selectedWeapon = 0;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    SelectWeapon();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;

    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
    {
        if (selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
            selectedWeapon = 0;
        else
            selectedWeapon++;
    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
    {
        if (selectedWeapon <= transform.childCount - 1)
            selectedWeapon = 0;
        else
            selectedWeapon--;
    }

    if (previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }
}

void SelectWeapon ()
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
    {
        if (i == selectedWeapon)
            weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        else
            weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want your "down wheel" block to work a little differently:

```
    if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
    {
        if (selectedWeapon <= 0)
            selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
        else
            selectedWeapon--;
    }
```